# stating which conditions have been matched in linq where

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, select

I have a linq statement as such

```
dbContext.Items   
.Where(
p =>

  (p.Client.Contact != null && p.Client.Contact.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
  ||
  (p.Client.Contact != null && p.Client.Contact.Surname.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
  ||
  (p.PolicyNumber != null && p.PolicyNumber.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
  ||
  (
    p.PolicyLivesAssureds
    .Where(
        pl =>
        pl.Contact != null && pl.Contact.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())
        || pl.Contact.Surname.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())
        ).Count() > 0
  )
)
).OrderBy(p => p.IeUtem);
```

This is actually needed in an autocomplete. What I want to do is being able to know exactly which among my 5 conditions has been matched and display the particular item that has been matched. For example say that PolicyNumber has been matched i want to send only policynumber for that row and for others if name has been matched i want to send only the name for that row.

Is there a way to do this;

Comment: Since you are using `OR` I would recommend to break it up in 5 separate queries. This way it's easier to count the results of the separate components and store that result in a dedicated object. Although, since you are using an `OrderBy` you might want to merge the data again somewhere.

Comment: Do you use C#6.0? It you so, some expression can be simplified like: `p.Client.Contact != null && p.Client.Contact.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())` to `p.Client.Contact?.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())`

Answer (score 0):

The question becomes how do you want to know which queries match. For example you could do something like this

```
class AutoCompleteItem {
    String Text {get; set;}
    Item Item {get; set;}
}

var firstNames = dbContext.Items.Select(p => new AutoCompleteItem { Name = p.Client.Contract.FirstName, Item = p})

var lastNames =  dbContext.Items.Select(p => new AutoCompleteItem { Name = p.Client.Contract.SurName, Item = p})

var result = firstName.Union(lastNames).Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchText)).OrderBy(a => a.Item.IeUtem);
```

Now AutcompleteItem is a class that contains the text you want (and possibly any other fields you need, like information which field it was that matched)

The Idea here is the MVVM patttern. You have your model (the items). Now you need to construct a viewModel (AutoCompleteItems) that actual aids you in displaying what you want.

Comment: I can do three queries, but i am limited to number of database call i make, i wanted to do one query

Comment: Linq will only execute your query when you actually use the results. So when you do the final ToList it should execute the whole query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more of a food for thought answer as it has flaws in it's approach, but I think it does solve your problem:

```
double[] items = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
IEnumerable<Tuple<double, int>> results = items.Select(x =>
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var condition in new Func<bool>[]
            {
                // TODO: Write conditions here.
                () => x == 1,
                () => x == 2
            })
        {
            if (condition() == true)
                return index;
            else
                index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }).Zip(items, (matchedCondtion, item) => Tuple.Create(item, matchedCondtion))
    .Where(x => x.Item2 != -1);
```

I've used a simple double array as an example of the collection to filter, but it's just an example, you can use anything.

The first select returns an integer for each element in the collection. If there is a condition match, it returns the index of the condition. If there is not match it returns -1.

It does this by enumerating over the Func collection and returning the index of the first true condition (emulating the short circuiting of the || operator). If no conditions match it simply returns -1 after evaluating all conditions.

These results are then zipped back up with the original collection (using a Tuple), mapping each element with the index of its matching condition (or -1).

So the example would return:

```
{ 1, 0 },
{ 2, 1 },
{ 3, -1 },
{ 4, -1 },
{ 5, -1 }
```

This result is then simply filtered using `Where` to remove any entries with -1, leaving you with a collection of elements that matched a condition and the index of the condition that matched (in the form of a Tuple).

So to customize this for your solution, you can remove the example conditions and place whatever number of conditions you want at:

```
// TODO: Write conditions here.
```